# Cipher Riddle (intermediate)

Tags: riddle, cipher, knowledge

You must decode and answer it! Here it is:

> 00101010 01001101 01100111 01101000 00100000 01101101 01110110 00100000 01101000 01110100 01110111 00100000 01101101 01101110 01110111 00100000 01100101 01110100 01101101 00100000 01110111 01100001 01101000 01101001 00100000 01111001 01100001 01101111 01110111 00100000 01101001 01101101 01101111 01110111 01101000 01110100 01110011 01101110 01110101 00100000 01101000 01101101 00100000 01110111 01100001 01101000 00111011 00001010 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 01101101 01100111 01101000 00100000 01101101 01110110 00100000 01101000 01110100 01110111 00100000 01101001 01101000 01101010 01101101 01101110 01110101 00100000 01111001 01100001 01101111 01110111 00100000 01101001 01101101 01101111 01110111 01101000 01110100 01110011 01101110 01110101 00100000 01101001 01100101 01110111 01110111 01101000 00101110 00101010

Sorry for the three posts today! I am new to this site and eager to share!

Comment: No problem! We'd love to hear your puzzles! :D Welcome to Puzzling SE btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> "What is sweeter than honey?
>   What is stronger than a lion?"

And the steps:

> First, decode binary to ascii to get
>  `*Mgh mv htw mnw etm wahi yaow imowhtsnu hm wah;
>    mgh mv htw ihjmnu yaow imowhtsnu iewwh.*`
>
>  Then use substitution cipher solver (for instance, this one: https://quipqiup.com/) to get the following
>  `*Out of the one who eats came something to eat;
>    out of the strong came something sweet.*`
>  Quick google search reveals that it's a biblical passage from Judges, to which the answer was
>  `"What is sweeter than honey?
>   What is stronger than a lion?"`

Comment: Correct, good job!

Comment: Darn it! If I knew that website! Good job though :D

Answer (score 4):

Here is (probably not correct) a part of the answer:

> Taking all the groups of digits and interpreting them as binary, then using the ASCII code for each integer, we end up with the string *Mgh mv htw mnw etm wahi yaow imowhtsnu hm wah; mgh mv htw ihjmnu yaow imowhtsnu iewwh.*

This seems like a

> sentence, as there is a semicolon and a period at the end. Also, some words such as "yaow" and "mv" appear twice so this could be another substitution.

Anyways, hope this helps for anyone interested! I'll keep on solving and edit it later.

### EDIT

From here we see that

> Plugging it into a substitution cipher we get **Out of the one who eats came something to eat; out of the strong came something sweet.**

Which is

> An experience of Samson in the Bible.

And then we end up with

> "What is sweeter than honey? What is stronger than a lion?"

Comment: @MicCrozier am I on the right track? I feel like I'm way off :(

Comment: Sorry NL628, not quite, but keep searching! :)

Comment: @MicCrozier Okay completed it :D

Comment: Good job, NL628!